# Pattern recognition in LUIS app : Please find {Entity1} {Entity2}{Entity3} documents

Tags: azure-language-understanding

We have created the LUIS app,
where defined the pattern & utterance in one of the intent.
as  "Please find {Entity1} {Entity2}{Entity3} documents"
where are all entities are simple entities ,

we have tested most of the utterances like Please find abc bcd tst documents
for some example it works (entity recognition works properly) but other does not

Please suggest suitable way for correct entity recognition for every utterance 
starting with Please find ... ....  ... (ending with)documents

Swati

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

When matching a pattern, LUIS looks for entities first. [Simple entities are machine-learned entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#types-of-entities) so in order for LUIS to find them it needs to know what those entities are. LUIS won't be able to recognize the simple entities in your pattern unless those entities are present in utterances so that LUIS understands what those entities represent. You can read more about patterns [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-patterns).

I think it's likely that you don't really need a pattern in your case. Go ahead and try adding utterances to your intent like "Please find abc bcd tst documents" and then mark the entities in the utterances.

Comment: Hi Kyle, we have already tried this.. but next time I tried with Please find xyx xyv cvb documents. it wont recognize entities on it's own  .. the middle "x.." of this utterence can be any sequence of letters

Comment: Again, simple entities are machine-learned. How is LUIS supposed to find your entities when you're not using actual words? How is LUIS supposed to know what xyx means?

Comment: but can we use Sentence "Please share " + 3 words next to it as pattern?